# JW Player with Youtube link don't work on IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, jwplayer

Please help me!

I have code such as! This code good working on Firefox and Chrome, but when run on IE then the page is blank.

```
<body>
<div id='player'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('player').setup({
        file: 'http://www.youtube.com/v/8pjJ-Czqpps?modestbranding=1&rel=0&fs=0',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9',
        skin: 'five',
        logo: {
            file: "https://sites.google.com/site/gitluutru/home/khuluutrufilegmit/logo.png",
            link: 'http://www.youtube.com/v/8pjJ-Czqpps?modestbranding=1&rel=0&fs=0',
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please give us a link to your page, rather than just a code snippet.

Comment: Yeah, please provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

Tools>ActiveX Filtering (turns ActiveX filtering on/off) - Active X filtering can block Flash which uses ActiveX technology on MSIE browsers (Netscape plugin on other browsers).

Tools>Manage Addons>Show All Addons.... locate Adobe Flash in your Addons list and ensure it is enabled and you have installed both x86 and x64 versions... (if your machine cpu is x64)

File>Properties to determine which IE Security zone your site maps to (Internet Expected)...

Tools>Internet Options>Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default".... depending on the IE Security zone there are security settings in IE for scripting of ActiveX controls and Java applets.

For testing purposes make sure that your site/localhost is mapping to the Internet Zone and that you are accepting the default IE Security zone settings.

If possible include a link to your website or a mashup with your questions so that we can visit the site to investigate.

Regards.